# How do I determine what will be selected when selecting a button disables it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, disabled-control

I'm using Windows Forms. I have a button that, when clicked, immediately disables itself (by setting `btnName.Enabled = false`). To my horror, I've discovered that this triggers the `AfterSelect` event of a different control. The documentation for `Enabled` claims that disabled buttons can't be selected, so I suppose it makes sense that something else would be selected instantly. In fact, the stack trace event points to an external `Windows.Forms.SelectNextIfFocused()` method. This gives me my question: How do I determine what will be selected when selecting a button disables it?

Comment: @rory.ap Do you mean the `TabIndex` property?

Comment: @rory.ap That seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably due to [the tab order of the controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-tab-order). Check out [the "TabIndex" property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex) on each control, which is an integer that indicates the order in which the controls will receive focus when, for example, you use the tab key on the keyboard or, in this case, when the control that currently has the focus becomes disabled.